# Rename all selected in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Let's say we have declared a shortcut in the using section of visual studio c# file:

```
using P = Project.Person;
```

When I double click the P it will select all appearances in the file. How do I change all of them at a time? Ctrl + . does not work, rename all also behaves strangely.
Thanks.

Comment: Right-click your P declaration then select rename

Comment: For me its f2 but that might be resharper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your `P` click `Ctrl+R` `Ctrl+R` and rename all of them.

Comment: OK I followed what you said I select P at the declaration ctrl+r ctrl+r and the dialog tells me that 0 references in 0 files will be renamed all though declaration is used several times down in the code section?

Comment: @marto please take a look at the recording I have just done. http://take.ms/vMVaI

Comment: If these are separate declarations, then you will have to rename them per declaration.

Comment: @Samvel Petrosov thanks for the video, it is very nicely explained but for some reason in my project codebase (which is huge) visual studio cannot do the renaming. I tried it in a new clean solution and it works. Any idea if it somehow conflicts with regions, multiple classes or attributes?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b I am calling static method and constants

Comment: @marto if you have multiple classes in multiple files, you will have to rename every shortcut seperately for every file. Because your every shortcut is working only for the scope of that file.

Comment: I've meant multiple classes in the same file.